# JTextFeild.requestDefaultFocus()

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Can anybody explain the use of **JTextFeild.requestDefaultFocus()** in a simple program.
Example.

```
class test_of_request_Default_Focus
   {

    JPanel main_panel;
    JTextArea test_text_area;
    JTextArea test_text_area1;

    public void main( String[] arg)
    {

    test_text_area = new JTextArea(3);
    test_text_area1 = new JTextArea(3);

        main_panel.add(test_text_area);
        main_panel.add(test_text_area1);

        main_panel.setVisible(true);
    }
   }
```

Now like to do is

```
test_text_area1.requestDefaultFocus();
```

Comment: You can find the answer [here (JComponent requestDefaultFocus)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestDefaultFocus()). Don't use it though, it's deprecated.

Comment: Note that `JTextField` and `JTextArea` aren't the same thing.

Comment: @Brandon Ibbotson Thank you, What I have is one JTextFeild and a JTextArea. Like to set focus on JTextFeild on start. By default focus is set to JTextArea.